# Matching multiple array value to row in csv file slow

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, csv, numpy

I have a numpy array consisting of about 1200 arrays containing 10 values each. np.shape = 1200, 10. Each element has a value between 0 and 5,7 million.

Next I have a .csv file with 3800 lines. Every line contains 2 values. The first value indicates a range the second value is an identifier. The first and last 5 rows of the .csv file:

```
509,47222
1425,47220
2404,47219
4033,47218
6897,47202
...,...
...,...
...,...
5793850,211
5794901,186
5795820,181
5796176,43
5796467,33
```

The first columns goes up until it reaches 5,7 million. For each value in the numpy array I want to check the first column of the .csv file. I have for example the value `3333`, this means the identifier belonging to `3333` is `47218`. Each row indicates that from the first column of the row before till the first column of this row, eg: `2404 - 4033` the identifier is `47218`.

Now I want to get the identifier for each value in the numpy array, then I want to safe the identifier and the frequency of which this identifier is found in the numpy array. Which means I need to loop 3800 times over a csv file of 12000 lines and subsequently ++ an integer. This process takes about 30 seconds which is way too long.

This is the code I am currently using:

```py
    numpy_file = np.fromfile(filename, dtype=np.int32)
    #some code to format numpy_file correctly

    with open('/identifer_file.csv') as read_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(read_file, delimiter=',')
        csv_reader = list(csv_reader)

        identifier_dict = {}
        for numpy_array in numpy_file:
            for numpy_value in numpy_array:
                #there are 12000 numpy_value in numpy_file

                for row in csv_reader:
                    last_identifier = 0

                    if numpy_value <= int(row[0]):
                        last_identifier = int(row[1])

                        #adding the frequency of the identifier in numpy_file to a dict
                        if last_identifier in identifier_dict:
                            identifier_dict[last_identifier] += 1
                        else:
                            identifier_dict[last_identifier] = 1
                    else:
                        continue

                    break

        for x, y in identifier_dict.items():
            if(y > 40):
                print("identifier: {} amount of times found: {}".format(x, y))
```

What algorithm should I implement to speed up this process?

**Edit**
I have tried folding the numpy array to a 1D array, so it has 12000 values. This has no real affect on the speed. Latest test was 33 seconds

Comment: So the ndarray is like: `a = np.random.randint(0, 5700000, (1200,10))`?

Comment: ... `NameError: name 'vector_pos' is not defined` : please provide [mcve].

Comment: @wwii Yes indeed, fixed vector_pos to numpy_value

Comment: The `break` statement in the inner for loop causes the loop to *stop* after the first iteration. Was that intended?

Comment: when numpy<= int(row[0]) == true then it should break. else it should continue to check every row until if statements is true

Comment: Does your code produce the correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup:

```
import numpy as np
import collections
np.random.seed(100)
numpy_file = np.random.randint(0, 5700000, (1200,10))

#'''range, identifier'''
read_file = io.StringIO('''509,47222
1425,47220
2404,47219
4033,47218
6897,47202
5793850,211
5794901,186
5795820,181
5796176,43
5796467,33''')

csv_reader = csv.reader(read_file, delimiter=',')
csv_reader = list(csv_reader)

# your example code put in a function and adapted for the setup above
def original(numpy_file,csv_reader):
    identifier_dict = {}
    for numpy_array in numpy_file:
        for numpy_value in numpy_array:
            #there are 12000 numpy_value in numpy_file

            for row in csv_reader:
                last_identifier = 0

                if numpy_value <= int(row[0]):
                    last_identifier = int(row[1])

                    #adding the frequency of the identifier in numpy_file to a dict
                    if last_identifier in identifier_dict:
                        identifier_dict[last_identifier] += 1
                    else:
                        identifier_dict[last_identifier] = 1
                else:
                    continue

                break

#    for x, y in identifier_dict.items():
#        if(y > 40):
#            print("identifier: {} amount of times found: {}".format(x, y))
    return identifier_dict
```

---

Three solutions each *vectorizing* some of the operations.  The first function consumes the least memory, the last consumes the most memory.

```
def first(numpy_file,r):
    '''compare each value in the array to the entire first column of the csv'''
    alternate = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for value in np.nditer(numpy_file):
        comparison = value < r[:,0]
        identifier = r[:,1][comparison.argmax()]
        alternate[identifier] += 1
    return alternate

def second(numpy_file,r):
    '''compare each row of the array to the first column of csv'''
    alternate = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for row in numpy_file:
        comparison = row[...,None] < r[:,0]
        indices = comparison.argmax(-1)
        id_s = r[:,1][indices]
        for thing in id_s:
            #adding the frequency of the identifier in numpy_file to a dict
            alternate[thing] += 1
    return alternate

def third(numpy_file,r):
    '''compare the whole array to the first column of csv'''
    alternate = collections.defaultdict(int)
    other = collections.Counter()
    comparison = numpy_file[...,None] < r[:,0]
    indices = comparison.argmax(-1)
    id_s = r[:,1][indices]
    other = collections.Counter(map(int,np.nditer(id_s)))
    return other
```

The functions require the csv file be read into a numpy array:

```
read_file.seek(0)    #io.StringIO object from setup
csv_reader = csv.reader(read_file, delimiter=',')
r = np.array([list(map(int,thing)) for thing in csv_reader])

one = first(numpy_file, r)
two = second(numpy_file,r)
three = third(numpy_file,r)
assert zero == one
assert zero == two
assert zero == three
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You helped me out immensely